# Type of an auto initialized list

Tags: c++, types, initializer-list, auto

In the C++ code below, what is type of `a`? `typeid` returns `St16initializer_listIPKcE`

```
auto a = { "lol", "life" };
```

Comment: What standard are you using? 11, 14, 17? auto initializer_list has been a bit volatile...

Comment: `const volatile auto a = { "trollin'" };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have

```
auto a = { "lol", "life" };
```

The compiler will try to deduce a `std::initializer_list` where the type is what all of the elements are.  In this case `"lol"` and `"life"` are both a `const char[]` so you have a `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

If on the other have you had something like

```
auto foo = { 1, 2.0 };
```

Then you would have a compiler error since the element types are different.

The rules for auto deduction of intializer list are as follows with one expection

```
auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
auto x3{ 1, 2 }; // error: not a single element
auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list<int>
```

The expection is that before C++17

```
auto x5{ 3 };
```

is a `std::intializer_list<int>` where in C++17 and most compilers that already adopted the rule it is deduced as a `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is [`std::intializer_list<char const*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

If you want to learn non-mangled name of a type, you can use the undefined template trick:

```
template<typename T>
void get_type_name(T&&);
```

then call it

```
auto a = { "",  ""};
get_type_name(a);
```

You should get a readable error message stating something along the lines of

```
undefined reference to `void get_type_name<std::initializer_list<char const*>&>(std::initializer_list<char const*>&)'
```