# Auto declaration of map iterator error on GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, auto, c++17

I have a map defined as:

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::string> spCalls;
```

I also have a function that returns the string, given the key. It is defined as:

```
std::string spGetCallString(unsigned int key)
{
    auto iter{ spCalls.find(key) };

    return iter->second;
}
```

When attempting to compile this, with GCC, I get an error which says

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type
'std::initializer_list < std::_Rb_tree_iterator < std::pair < const unsigned int, std::basic_string < char> > > >'

 return iter->second;"
```

I just cannot make any sense of this and I can't see why my code shouldn't work. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type of an auto initialized list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094160/type-of-an-auto-initialized-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before C++17, [auto type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts) for braced initializer will always yield type of instantiation of `std::initializer_list`, so for `auto iter{ spCalls.find(key) };`, the type of `iter` would be `std::initializer_list<std::map<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator>`, which doesn't match the usage at all.

Since C++17 you'll get the correct type for it, i.e. `std::map<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator`.

> In direct-list-initialization (but not in copy-list-initalization),
>   when deducing the meaning of the [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) from a braced-init-list, the
>   braced-init-list must contain only one element, and the type of auto
>   will be the type of that element:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = {3}; // x1 is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x2{1, 2}; // error: not a single element
> auto x3{3};    // x3 is int (before C++17 it was std::initializer_list<int>)
> ```

If your compiler still doesn't support that, you could change braced initializer to other initializers, e.g.

```
auto iter = spCalls.find(key);
auto iter(spCalls.find(key));
```